# How to send email from windows phone 7 application

Tags: c#, windows-phone

In my Windows Phone 7 application I want to send an e-mail where the message body should contain the data from the  previous page.

```
private void Email_Send(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
EmailComposeTask emailComposeTask = new EmailComposeTask();

emailComposeTask.Subject = "message subject";
emailComposeTask.Body = "message body";
emailComposeTask.To = "recipient@example.com";
emailComposeTask.Cc = "cc@example.com";
emailComposeTask.Bcc = "bcc@example.com";
emailComposeTask.Show();
}
```

Now in the body part I want my data from the previous page. So how to do this?

```
if (this.NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("school_name"))
{
//if it is available, get parameter value
school = NavigationContext.QueryString["school_name"];
school.Text = date;
}
```

Please tell me how to pass the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
private void Email_Send(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
string previousValue = string.empty;
if (NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("school_name"))
      previousValue = NavigationContext.QueryString["school_name"];
EmailComposeTask emailComposeTask = new EmailComposeTask();
emailComposeTask.Subject = "message subject";
emailComposeTask.To = "recipient@example.com";
emailComposeTask.Cc = "cc@example.com";
emailComposeTask.Bcc = "bcc@example.com";
emailComposeTask.Body = previousValue ;
emailComposeTask.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

emailComposeTask.Body = + school;